# Insert into mysql from python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert a csv file into mysql.Here is my code.

```
path = r'C:\Users\ravi\Desktop\Book1.csv'
with open(path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', lineterminator=" ")
    for row in csv_data:
        print row
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtable (id,name) VALUES (%s, %s)" % row)
```

The error is:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtable (id,name) VALUES (%s, %s)" % row)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.
```

Please help me solve this

Comment: What is the value of `row` printed?

Comment: it is a list with first row of csv file. In this case it is ['id', 'name'] the headers of csv file.

Comment: Okay, quick question, what if you define the reader as `csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')`?

Comment: The same result .no change ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using right delimiter???

```
csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', lineterminator=" ")
```

For csv, shouldn't it be ,

```
csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

Actually for csv.reader(),

> A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Try this for insert statement:-

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtable (id,name) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (row[0],row[1]))
```

Comment: I have tried it by changing the definition of reader,How ever the same error persits. i think the error is with the insert statement

Comment: Thanks for correcting the reader definition.Could you pls help me with insert statement

Comment: Thanks a lot That worked.Can u pls help me how can i exclude the header  in csv file from getting inserted into my db

Comment: @venkatsai:- Please mark it solved if it solved your problem. In this way it will help others looking for similar problem...